# execute php script and get values with ajax from js script

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, input

I've a A.php with somes inputs:

```
<input id="serverName" class="fullInput" type="text" name="serverName" placeholder="Nom du serveur" />
<input id="serverIP" class="fullInput" type="text" name="ip" placeholder="Adresse IP" />
<input id="serverWebsite" class="fullInput" type="text" name="site" placeholder="URL du site" />
```

I get them values in a B.js (and I re-use them for some things in JS)

```
var serverName = $.trim($('#serverName').val());
var serverIP = $.trim($('#serverIP').val());
var serverWebsite = $.trim($('#serverWebsite').val());
```

But now I've to write them in DB (php script) and I need to get this value again ? So it can be send in Ajax ?

```
$.ajax({
url: "C.php",
method: "POST",
data: {
serverName: serverName.val(),
serverIP: serverIP.val(),
serverWebsite: serverWebsite.val()
},
dataType: "html"
});
```

Here my C.php will execute a post in DB with the variable serverName / serverWebsite / serverIP ? And this script can be launched with my ajax code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JavaScript change some code in Ajax like this

```
$.ajax({
url: "C.php",
method: "POST",
data: {serverName: serverName,serverIP: serverIP,serverWebsite: serverWebsite },
dataType: "html",
success: function(ans){
alert(ans);
}
});
```

and here your c.php file code like this

```
<?php
$serverName = $_POST['serverName'];
$serverIP= $_POST['serverIP'];
$serverWebsite= $_POST['serverWebsite'];

//here you need to write mysql code to insert it in to database or whatever process  
?>
```

this code useful for you :)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This ajax code alert "Success" but when I try to go in C.php after that, their is no value for my input, just the text:

<?php
        $serverName = $_POST['serverName'];
        $serverIP= $_POST['serverIP'];
        $serverWebsite= $_POST['serverWebsite'];
    
    echo "Le nom: $serverName";
    echo "L'ip: $serverIP";
    echo "Le site: $serverWebsite";
    ?>

Comment: you replace alert("success ");  to alert(ans); work fine

Answer (score 0):

Your C.php would have code as below:

```
<?php
$serverName = $_POST['serverName'];
$serverIP= $_POST['serverIP'];
$serverWebsite= $_POST['serverWebsite'];

//here you need to write mysql code to insert it in to database or whatever process you want to do with this variables.

?>
```

Thanks
Amit